# Как подключить js-скрипт сразу к нескольким файлам?

Tags: javascript, html, bash

Здравствуйте.
Вот есть, допустим, папка, а в ней - файлы page1, page2,.. page57.
Должен ведь быть способ подключить js-скрипт ко всем файлам сразу, а не вручную прописывать подключение в хедере каждого файла?

Comment: [Какое забавное совпадение](http://hashcode.ru/questions/356945/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-js-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC).

Comment: @Etki, вот, оказывается, параллельные миры существуют)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не совсем понятен.
Если Вы имеете в виду статические страницы, то, скорее всег, только в ручную... Либо сделать скрипт, который включит подключение в каждый файл. Если Вы пользуетесь веб-сервером (Apache, Nginx,..), то уточните, каким пользуетесь. Если еще используете php либо ruby, node.js..., также напишите - тогда проще будет дать рецепт!